# Custom Jackson Deserializer Per Endpoint

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

I am wondering if there is a way to customize the Jackson Deserializer per method:

```
@PostMapping("/first")
public void firstMethod(@RequestBody User user)
{
  ...
}
@PostMapping("/second")
public void secondMethod(@RequestBody User user)
{
  ...
}
```

In each endpoint, a User class is needed. If I understand it correctly, if the HTTP request is sent to an endpoint with data, Jackson parser will call the setters with corresponding names to the attributes in the body data and try and set everything as a 1:1. How do I change how these get set per endpoint.

For example, in firstMethod(), the data body gets mapped to a User class in 1 fashion and in secondMethod(), the data body gets mapped to a User class in another fashion:

```
const data = {first: 1, second: 2, third: 3}
```

firstMethod will create a User of

```
{something: 1, something2: 2, something3: 3}
```

secondMethod will create a User of:

```
{something: 3, something2: 1, something3: 2}
```

As an example.

Answer (score 0):

You could just inject the `HttpServletRequest` and map the data manually:

```java
@Autowired
ObjectMapper objectMapper;

@PostMapping
public void foo(@RequestBody User user, HttpServletRequest request) {
    JsonNode json = objectMapper.readTree(request.getReader());
    // use JsonNode object to parse / map the data however you want
}
```

---

But I suggest you should ask yourself the question: Why?

If you got two different JSON representations for the same Java Class, you probably should use two different Java DTO classes.

Comment: I may have misrepresented my question. In each endpoint, the represented class is still being created but the mapped fields are different. For example, in the first endpoint, Jackson parser may parse [1,2,3] into firstAttr=1, secondAttr=2, thirdAttr=3 and in the second endpoint, it may parse the same array as firstAttr=3, secondAttr=2 and thirdAttr=1. They are not representing different DTOs, merely changing how Jackson parser maps the header data to the DTO.